# Building Spark from source error: There is no POM in this directory

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I am trying to build spark from source following https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html. I have completed following steps

1. Installed JDK 18
2. Installed Maven 3.6
3. Installed Scala 2.13
4. Set JAVA_HOME
5. Set Maven path
6. Verified that maven, java and scala are installed
7. cloned the spark repo

[image]

Problem:

When I execute following command

./build/mvn -DskipTests clean package

to build spark from source after installing maven I get following error

[image]

I have tried uninstalling maven and tried building with maven inside C:/Spark/spark/build. That doesn't recognizes 'mvn'
It simply says 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command'

Please suggest what I might be doing wrong here and how can I build spark from source on Windows 11.

Thanks
RA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says: `Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.`

Please run `./build/mvn -DskipTests clean package` command from `C:/Spark/spark/` directory instead of `C:/Spark/spark/build/`.